# Getting SMTP error while using PHpmailer to send mail through my website

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am trying to send email from my website through PHP Mailer class in PHP. 
The code is given below but when I am trying to send the email, I am getting these two errors:

> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Message could not be sent.
>
> Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

What is going wrong. Please help?

```
<?php

// $email and $message are the data that is being
// posted to this page from our html contact form
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

// When we unzipped PHPMailer, it unzipped to
// public_html/PHPMailer_5.2.0
require("lib/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

// set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();

// As this email.php script lives on the same server as our email server
// we are setting the HOST to localhost
$mail->Host = "localhost";  // specify main and backup server

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication

// When sending email using PHPMailer, you need to send from a valid email address
// In this case, we setup a test email account with the following credentials:
// email: send_from_PHPMailer@bradm.inmotiontesting.com
// pass: password
$mail->Username = "send_from_myemail@host.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password

// $email is the user's email address the specified
// on our contact us page. We set this variable at
// the top of this page with:
// $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$mail->From = $email;

// below we want to set the email address we will be sending our email to.
$mail->AddAddress("myemail@host.com", "namit pathak");

// set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
// set email format to HTML
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "You have received feedback from your website!";

// $message is the user's message they typed in
// on our contact us page. We set this variable at
// the top of this page with:
// $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $message;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your email's username and password on this line, currently you are using the original dummy settings:

```
$mail->Username = "send_from_myemail@host.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "password";
```

Answer (score 0):

you only put the host as localhost at a time you must configured your local smtp server

```
$mail->Host = "localhost";
```

if you have google accounts means try it

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.google.com";
```